# Read/Write File : Write to line in certain order - Python

Tags: python, file

I'm have couple of problems with my code. I understand one of them but not sure how to fix it. Code is meant to read the text file.

FORMAT OF TXT FILE:

```
204 jack sparrow

http://testlink.com/test123

123 Doughboy®

http://testlink.com/test346

348 ༺༃ོེċℏυƿᾰċᾰ♭Իᾰ༂ི༻

http://testlink.com/testr55
```

and so on..

Next it should write another file with the output as follow:

OUTPUT FILE FORMAT:

```
204 http://testlink.com/test123&u_link=jack_sparrow

123 http://testlink.com/test346&u_link=Doughboy®

348 http://testlink.com/testr55&u_link=༺༃ོེċℏυƿᾰċᾰ♭Իᾰ༂ི༻
```

and so on...

My output looks like this :

```
204 jack_sparow

http://testlink.com/test123&u_link=123_Doughboy®

http://testlink.com/test346&u_link=348_༺༃ོེċℏυƿᾰċᾰ♭Իᾰ༂ི༻
```

and so on.

For some reason when the input file starts at the first line, that line doesn't get processed and is not present in outcome file. When first line is left empty in input file the output file looks as above. Moving it to the next lines in input file makes no difference in output file. This is my first issue. Second one is that i cant figure out how to split the line of the input file with number and name then move number to the front of line and name to the back of link in output file,

My code looks like this :

```
for line in open('test2.txt'): #reading file

rec = line.strip()

rec = rec.replace(" ", "_")    #Need whitespaces and brackets removed from link so i replaced them with low line
rec = rec.replace("(", "_")
rec = rec.replace(")", "_") 

level = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')  #line with number and name always starts with number

link = ('h')            #line with link always starts with letter h as in http://

name = (rec[3:])       

if rec.startswith(link):

    f = open("test5.txt","a")   

f.write(rec + "&u_link=")      #writes link and append $u_link= to the end of the line and this is the place where i want to append the name 

if rec.startswith(level) :

    f = open("test5.txt","a") 

    f.write(rec + "\n\n")      # this is where i write name and number
```

I know the code is far from perfect but I just started my programming adventure and this is my second attempt to accomplish the same task. I decided to use read/write file method after my raw_input attempt failed due to symbols and fancy fonts present in names that couldn't be processed by command line in Windows but worked fine on Linux console(cmd in Windows is using different encoding than utf-8).

This is my first attempt code that worked fine but relayed on manual input rather than file:

```
print "level?",      
level = raw_input()     # file should be sorted by this variable
print "link?",
link = raw_input()     
print "name?",         # Problem with fonts and symbols
name = raw_input()
name = name.replace(" ", "")  #This removes spaces from the name as URL         cant  have spaces 
ul = "&u_link="        #This have to be appended to the link followed by  the name
el = "\n"              #Empty line to separate links in test.txt file
f = open("test.txt","a") 
f.write(el+level+" -- "+link+ul+name+el)   #file writing 
print level+" -- "+link+ul+name            #printing in the console just to see if works
```

I hope it explains what I'm trying to do. All the help and advice much appreciated. Forgive me for any and all mistakes .. English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed that if i reverse the file using reversed() it fixes my problem. For some reason python would always read 'link' first regardless on txt file format. 
After a lil bit of research i found another way of completing the task that uses list of strings and works regardless on txt file format meaning it will work for the instances where link is under the line that contains data or above it.

Here is the code I used to complete the task using reversed():

```
import os
import glob

for line in reversed(open("test2.txt").readlines()):
    rec = line.strip()
    rec = rec.replace("<", "_")
    rec = rec.replace(">", "_")
    rec = rec.replace("&", "n")
    rec = rec.replace(" ", "_")
    rec = rec.replace("(", "_")
    rec = rec.replace(")", "_") 
    rec = rec.replace('"', "_")
    rec = rec.replace("'", "_")
    level = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
    link = ('h')
    if rec.startswith(link):
    f = open("temp.txt","a")
    f.write(rec + "&u_link=")  
    elif rec.startswith(level) :
    f = open("temp.txt","a") 
    f.write(rec + "\n\n")   
    f.close()
for line in reversed(open("temp.txt").readlines()):
    lines = line.strip()    
    f = open("hitlistlinks.txt","a") 
    f.write(lines + "\n")    

files = glob.glob('temp.txt')
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

Notice i created temp file in process that I remove with :

```
files = glob.glob('temp.txt')
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)
```

at the end of my code. In order for this way to work I had to import os and glob methods.

Now I wasn't entirely satisfied with the solution so i did more research. 
Eventually I wrote another code with some help from  http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/
Highly recommend guys from Learnprogrammin @reddit. Got almost instant help and lots of good advice so if u fairly new to programming that's a good place to check out if u get stacked with something.They also have pretty active IRC channel on freenode #Learnprogramming.

This is the final code that is much cleaner and does the job:

```
# Open the file
with open("test3.txt", "r") as f:

# Here we're going to clean up the input file to wipe out
# any whitespace at the beginning or end of each line
    cleaned_lines = []
    for line in f:
        cleaned_lines.append(line.strip())

# Now we'll recombine it back into a single string of text 
# with the lines separated by the \n character
    all_text = "\n".join(cleaned_lines)

# Split the text on blank lines.  Groups should now be a list
# of strings, where each group contains two adjacent lines 
# that contain a link and a strip of data
    groups = all_text.split("\n\n")

# Now we'll go through each group and break it apart into the
# two separate lines.  One of them will start with an "http" 
# and that one will be our link.

    for group in groups:

        line1, line2 = [x for x in group.split("\n") if x]
        if line1.startswith("http"):
            link = line1
            rec = line2 
        elif line2.startswith("http"):
            link = line2
            rec = line1
        else:
        # If one of the two lines doesn't start with "http" we 
        # have a group that doesn't have a link.  
        # I'll just throw 
        # an error and bring the program to a halt.
            raise Exception("This group is missing a link! format(group))

        # At this point the link variable contains the link, and 
        # the data variable contains the other line. Now we can process the input file as intended 
        # and it will work on either file.
        rec = rec.replace("<", "_")
        rec = rec.replace(">", "_")
        rec = rec.replace("&", "n")
        rec = rec.replace(" ", "_")
        rec = rec.replace("(", "_")
        rec = rec.replace(")", "_") 
        rec = rec.replace('"', "_")
        rec = rec.replace("'", "_")
        f = open("hitlist.txt","a")
        f.write(link + "&u_link=" + rec + "\n\n")
        f.close()
```

I hope this will help others with similar problem and show them two different approaches to the same problem. FYI there is more than two.